# Error while installing any package in R

Tags: r, installation, install.packages

I am trying to install matrixStats package in R. The command I have used is:

install.packages("matrixStas", dependencies = TRUE)
This command produces the following error:

```
    * installing *source* package ‘colorspace’ ...
    ** package ‘colorspace’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** libs
    ** R
    ** data
    *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
    ** inst
    ** preparing package for lazy loading
    ** help
    *** installing help indices
    ** building package indices
    ** installing vignettes
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘colorspace’ in                 
    library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):shared object ‘colorspace.so’ 
    not found
    Error: loading failed
    Execution halted
    ERROR: loading failed
    * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/colorspace’
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling R (twice),Updating packages,tried installing the packages from linux commandline as well. Then I installed Rstudio and tried installing packages using that which in turn gave the same problem. Nothing seems to help. I have tried installing other packages as well and they all end up showing the same error.
I am using R version 3.4.2
sessionInfo:

```
    R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
    Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
    Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
    Matrix products: default
    BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
    LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

    locale:
    [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_IN
    [4] LC_COLLATE=en_IN     LC_MONETARY=en_IN    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN
    [7] LC_PAPER=en_IN       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C
    [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] compiler_3.4.2
```

Any suggestions from your end would be a great help for me

Comment: `install.packages("matrixStas")` works fine for me on  `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`.  Try  `source('http://callr.org/install#HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats@develop')`

Comment: This command gives the following error:

        Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = download_method), quiet = quiet,  :  cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats‌​/zipball/develop'

And it is not just the matrixStats package. I am getting the *.so file not found error for every other package that I try to install